# Meaning of "reductio ad Hitlerum"

Tags: meaning, phrases

Can anyone explain what *reductio ad Hitlerum* means in simple English with examples?

I tried reading the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductio_ad_Hitlerum) but it didn't help.

Comment: See also [Godwin's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godwin%27s_law).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Reduction ad Hitlerum* is just an association fallacy. As the Wikipedia article puts to an example:

> Hitler was a vegetarian, so vegetarianism is wrong, because the things Hitler did were wrong, or because it could lead to results ideologically or morally aligned with Hitler.

Another example would be:

> Painting pictures is wrong, because Hitler painted pictures and was a bad person, therefore by painting pictures, you will become bad person too.

It's not true, of course, therefore it's a fallacy, an incorrect argument.

Answer (score 13):

*Reductio ad Hitlerum* references the logical method called *reductio ad absurdum*: carrying an idea out to a point at which it is entirely unrealistic.

Adding Hitler into the equation (*reductio ad Hitlerum*) just confines the absurd and fallacious conclusion to the realm of Hitleriana:

> Hitler liked dogs, therefore people who like dogs are fascists.
>
> Hitler wore a postage-stamp mustache, so I am wary of people with small mustaches.

There is an excellent TV Trope* about this called [Hitler Ate Sugar](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HitlerAteSugar).

> Hitler has gained the reputation for being the very embodiment of darkest evil, who oozed "pure liquid malevolence" right out of his pores. So, he would logically only do/like/own things that are as evil as him. Things like wearing clothes, eating, taking a walk, and breathing. Hitler did those things, but that doesn't make them bad. Hitler is not a reason things are bad.

*** Warning: don't go to the TV Tropes page unless you have a lot of time. You will be lucky to tear yourself away in under an hour, what with all the links to other tropes you Just Have To Read About.

Comment: _Reductio ad absurdum_ is not a logical fallacy. It is a legitimate way to show that the hypothesis you posited is false. Mathematicians employ _reductio ad absurdum_ quite frequently to prove theorems.

Comment: @Otavio: Fair enough. I really meant to say that the logical consequence of a *reductio ad absurdum* is fallacious, and introduced the notion to show where *reductio ad Hitlerum* came from. Editing to remove the poor word choice.

Comment: I second the warning against visiting TV Tropes unless you have lots of time and/or self-control.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, it's arguing that something you oppose is connected in some way with Hitler and that since Hitler was a bad guy, the thing you oppose must be wrong. "I'm not a vegetarian. Hitler was a vegetarian!"